# if condition in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to put an if statement, like if the title is this, exclude those filenames else filenames = bla bla. but obviously not working, any ideas ?

```
SELECT
    SUM(streamlength)
FROM
    files,
    filemetadata
where
    files.id = filemetadata.id 
    AND title like 'abc'
    and (Time > '2013-01-01' and Time < '2013-08-06' )
    and 
    if((title like 'abc' AND Time > '2013-02-22'),
    (filename NOT like '%20121129%'
    AND filename NOT like '%20121204%'
    AND filename NOT like '%20121214%'
    AND  filename NOT like '%20121219%'
    AND filename NOT like '%20130109%'
    AND  filename NOT like '%20130114%'),filename like 
                   '%1111111%')
```

Comment: you might want to try a [case statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for that.  `where case when title='this' then filename else null end = filename or ... `  that way, if `title='this'` then `filename=filename` and the record is included.  if `title<>'this'`, then `null<>filename` and the row is excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading the intent of the SQL correctly:

```
SELECT
SUM(streamlength)
FROM
files,
filemetadata
where
files.id = filemetadata.id 
AND title like 'abc'
and (Time > '2013-01-01' and Time < '2013-08-06' )
and 
(
  ( 
    (title like 'DE-PIAE78' AND Time > '2013-02-22')
    AND
    (filename NOT like '%20121129%'
     AND filename NOT like '%20121204%'
     AND filename NOT like '%20121214%'
     AND  filename NOT like '%20121219%'
     AND filename NOT like '%20130109%'
     AND  filename NOT like '%20130114%')
  )
  OR
  (
    NOT ( (title like 'DE-PIAE78' AND Time > '2013-02-22') )
    AND ( filename like '%1111111%')
  )
)
```

This matches different filenames based on whether `(title like 'DE-PIAE78' AND Time > '2013-02-22')` is true or false.

Some SQL variants support an IF statement, but not all do.

Comment: that's probably what was wanted.. it looks good.

Comment: Ah, there's a mistake here too that will cause no rows to be returned.  The `title like 'abc'` conflicts with `title like 'DE-PIAE78'`